# Corda attachment upload

Tags: java, jersey, corda

I'm trying to add upload attachment in my Corda application but it's not working as I'm getting below error at start up itself.

> [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   com.test.agreementnegotiation.api.AgreementNegotiationApi.uploadFile(java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition)
>   at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST,
>   consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[],
>   suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS,
>   invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class
>   com.test.agreementnegotiation.api.AgreementNegotiationApi,
>   handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@14ab26a]},
>   definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   com.test.agreementnegotiation.api.AgreementNegotiationApi.uploadFile(java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition),
>   parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=tags,
>   defaultValue=], Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream,
>   source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class
>   org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition,
>   source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']

Below is the code -

```
@Path("upload")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@DefaultValue("") @FormDataParam("tags") String tags,
                               @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
                               @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition) {

        String fileName = fileDisposition.getFileName();
        saveFile(file, fileName);
        String fileDetails = "File saved at " + UPLOAD_FOLDER + " " + fileName + " with tags "+ tags;
        System.out.println(fileDetails);
        return Response.ok(fileDetails).build(); 
    }

    private void saveFile(InputStream file, String name) {
        try {
            /* Change directory path */
            java.nio.file.Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(UPLOAD_FOLDER + name);
            /* Save InputStream as file */
            Files.copy(file, path);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I searched on error and found  that we need to enable/resgiter MultiPartFeature.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=No+injection+source+found+for+a+parameter+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn5ePy5PbbAhWMOxQKHQHXAUkQrQIIUCgEMAI&biw=1280&bih=958

Whatever link I found they talk about changing web.xml or adding AppCong and I'm Not sure how it can be done in Corda sample project.

Corda team please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in node webserver has a default endpoint for uploading attachments, `/upload/*`. This endpoint is available out-of-the-box and does not need to be added in your API. You upload an attachment by making a POST request to this endpoint with the encoding type `multipart/form-data`.

For example:

```
<form action="/upload/attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="jar" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload blacklist</button>
</form>
```

You cannot provide your own additional endpoints for uploading attachments.

If you write your own node webserver (e.g. a [Spring webserver](https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver)), then there are no limitations.

Comment: Hi Joel,Thanks for HTML code but actually I'm more looking for javaside code. My implementation is based of Corda Template available on github. Templete API that i have used does not have any upload/attachment endponit [link] (https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/blob/release-V3/cordapp/src/main/java/com/template/TemplateApi.java) . Please share the reference link so that i an add custom code before upload on done on server.

Comment: The endpoint is available by default. You do not need to add it.

Comment: Thanks again Joel....I tried the endpoints and it worked :-) and gave me the hashId but then it raise two question - 1) Where is this file is uploaded ( what if i want to store it at some specific location. and 2) how can add this attachment to transaction so that it is available for other nodes.

Comment: Great! Can you raise these as separate questions please?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint of the deprecated webserver `/upload/attachment` does not work anymore in corda V4