# Corda custom file upload endpoint

Tags: java, corda

This is in continuation of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087768/corda-attachment-upload/51099607?noredirect=1#comment89282697_51099607). I have been able to call in-build endpoint for Corda attachment upload but I'm not sure how -

1) Where is this file uploaded (what if I want to store it at some specific location)?

and

2) How can I add this attachment to transaction so that it is available for other nodes?

I guess we need custom endpoint for these, so that I can upload the file to a given location and then pass the attachment(and it's hash code) in transactions.

Please assist.

Comment: One point 1- I guess I'm good as once upload is done - file is available on http://localhost:port/HasId but i'm still struggling with how the file would be available  to other interested nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Attachments are stored in the node's database, in the NODE_ATTACHMENTS table. You cannot specify a custom location.

2) You add an attachment to a transaction by hash:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class AddAttachmentFlow(private val attachmentHashString: String) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary: Party = TODO("Pick a notary.")

        val attachmentHash = SecureHash.parse(attachmentHashString)

        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
        txBuilder.addAttachment(attachmentHash)

        TODO("Finish building transaction and gathering required signatures.")
    }
}
```